# How can fix the git ignore faltal

Tags: git, gitignore

I use git as my vcs.

I have a reports folder, and add it in the git control, now I don't want trace this folder, then I add git ignore file, but it seems like git still trace this folder.

I search by Google, some web pages suggest `git rm --cached filename`, I run it, but get one fatal message `pathspec 'filename' did not match any files`.

How can fix this problem? And let git don't track these files?

My folder is this:

reports

|--readme.txt

|--report.html

|--screenshots

|----failed.png

And my .gitignore file is this

```
report/*.html
report/screenshots/
```

Comment: I add a new gitignore file in the reports folder, then `git status` don't track this folder files. Why?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you replace `filename` by the path to the file you want to untrack?

Comment: Hi CharlesB, I use the whole file path in the command. thx.

Comment: what does `git status` give?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to do `git rm -r --cached reports`

Comment: It does not work. I need use the .gitignore file in the reports folder. Thanks.